# Linq statement fails with dynamic where clause

Tags: linq, dynamic, where-clause

I want to retrieve commissions with a certain order number.

This works:

```
var expression = from commission in db.Auftraege 
                         where commission.Auftragsnummer == orderNbr
                         select new Commission() { EF_Commission = (commission as Auftrag) };

return expression.ToList();
```

However, if i transform this to use a dynamic where clause (because i want to apply some more filters), the where-clause does not seem to be applied. Instead, all commissions are returned instead of only those with a specific number:

```
//base query
var expression = from commission in db.Auftraege select new Commission() { EF_Commission = (commission as Auftrag) };

//now add a where clause if the input parameter was specified
if (orderNbr >= 0)
    expression.Where(commission => commission.EF_Commission.Auftragsnummer == orderNbr);

 return expression.ToList();
```

I have looked at a dozen examples but they all seem to do it this way. Does anybody have an idea why the second query ignores the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *assign* the interim `expression` to something (perhaps to itself). `expression.Where()` does not alter the existing query - it returns a new one.

So:

```
expression = expression.Where(...);
```

Comment: @user1870077 Ohhh... I've been there, plenty of times, myself!